# Difference between static controller and non static controller in play framework with Java

Tags: java, scala, playframework, guice

I was wondering if there was any significant advantage, or disadvantage, when using non-static controllers in a Java Play!Framework 2.2.x app.

I normally use the clasic static controllers that seem to be the default pattern for Play!.

But whenever I use Guice I obviously need to change that so that I can inject various services. For those wondering how this is done (you add an '@' in front of the function "path" in the routes file):

```
GET /api/something/someofthat   controllers.MyController.myStaticAction

GET /api/something/someother    @controllers.MyController.myNonStaticAction

public class MyController extends Controller {

    public static Result myStaticAction(){
        return ok("This is not a method.");
    }

    public Result myNonStaticAction(){
        return ok("This is not a static method.");
    }

}
```

Apart from the obvious and well documented advantage of dependency injection using Guice, it would seem to me that purely non static controllers would help in implementing thread-safe code. But I must say I am not sure of that. So my question is: **Can someone point me to cases in which NON-static controllers are recommended? And also cases where static controllers are called for?**

Also does it have any effect on the "scala wrapping" that play framework do on the controller functions?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

The dependency injection you mentioned is, to me, the reason why non-static controllers should always be used. It makes your code way easier to test.

It is true that non-static controllers can make it slightly easier to write thread-safe code. If you want to put mutable (and not shared across instances) state directly in your controller (which I do not recommend) it helps, however, the controller is only one part of your application, if you have non thread-safe code somewhere else it won't save you.

Can't think of any reason why you would want to use static controllers.